# How to view hostname locally, works external

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I have a webserver hooked, up I recently noticed that I can view the webserver htttp://music2share.ca from out side my network but when I try with in my network at home wont work, I edited the hosts file a bunch of times since I moved which was the only thing I change new modem, but I already port forward everything and the end is fine, just not locally.

Host file

hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.191 music2share.ca
127.0.1.1 music2share.music2share.ca music2share
127.0.0.1 music2share.ca
127.0.1.1 localhost
```

any one please, spent number of hours and I know its one simple address I am missing. Use to work before I moved to a new home.

Comment: With "inside your network", do you mean a computer other than music2share.ca ? What does `nslookup music2share.ca` show on this other computer?

Comment: yes I am trying to access music2share.ca from another computer inside the network, i believe it was working external but not sure now because i keep changing /etc/hosts file nslookup shows server: 192.168.0.1 address: 192.168.0.1#53 then under that says non-authoritative answer: name:music2share.ca address: 67.71.156.56

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. Check on the musicserver with `ifconfig` that its ip address is indeed 192.168.0.191 and remove the 127.* entries of the music server from the hosts file. This will keep dns lookup and traffic local. Make sure your router always assigns this ip-address to the music server.
2. Remove **all** hosts entries for the music server. DNS lookup will then likely go out to the Internet, but your router will notice that the traffic is internal anyway.

Comment: Tried both options still no go, I wonder if i have edit another file that could be interfering? Could this be possible?

Comment: Keeping option 1, can you ping a) the ip-address 192.168.0.191, b) the hostname music2share.ca from the machine from which you want to reach it? Does the access still work from external? Does the access work fom anywhere, like locally on the music2share.ca?

Comment: @Harold I tryed all your options waited 2 hours and try it still nothing each time, went to work web server works fine from there but any computer or device will not work at home a little frustrating because i can't edit code and check it as most code needs music2share.ca to work. When i tryed pinging music2share.ca and 192.168.0.191 from home I get no response?? what could this mean I even tryed pinging www.google.ca and same thing, keeps sending request but nothing gets recieved its like I dont hve internet connection from the server computer it self but yet it sends the info on the www.

Comment: Anyone have an idea? I have tryed other ports and there answer still nothing, thinking about un installing my ubuntu and re installing it, but what a pain in the ass.

Comment: If you cannot ping google, you're definitively in trouble, i.e. not connected to the Internet. But just to be sure: the computer you work on and 192.168.0.191 are both in your home network getting their IP-addresses from your home router?

Comment: yes, router is set up as dhcp, and my 192.168.0.191(server) has a static ip. I'm using a bell modem then to a dlink router , I have port forwarder correct as I can see port 80 on canyouseeme.org 2 days aga I could see 53 as well, today i can't but even 2 days ago when 53 was open still nothing. IF i tell you what it shows me when i run netstat -r would that help you out haha,I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I noticed i can't ping xx.xx.xx.xx anything , I found this code dig @192.168.0.1 "any address" it connects to it, so i notice its to do with gate way and such but how do i fix it? Still can access the web server from outside the network no problem.